# Simplifying question regarding sigma and permutation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEiqF.png

$$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i {n\choose i}.$$

How can THIS be simplified to 0 when n is positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let start from $$(1-x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i {n\choose i} x^i.$$

Comment: Sorry I still have no idea..

Comment: Compare GAVD's expression with yours. For what value of $x$ is it up to a constant the same as yours?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full solution in the event you didn't get it.
$$(1−x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(−1)^i{n \choose i}x^i$$
Set $x$ to be $1$
$$(1−1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(−1)^i{n \choose i}1^i$$
$$(0)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(−1)^i{n \choose i}$$
$$0=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(−1)^i{n \choose i}$$